# Filtering by any reference from another model

Tags: django, django-models

Let's assume we have the following two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    value = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
```

I can find any instance of `A` which is referenced by `B` where `B.value=123` using `A.objects.filter(b__value=123)`. But how do I find any instance of `A` which is referenced by any instance of `B`, without any further conditions? I would want to write `A.objects.filter(b)`, but that would not be a valid syntax. How do I write it then?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't test it since I have no Django around me, but I guess this one should do the job:

```
class B:
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='bObjects')
```

and you find all objects of A class, which are referenced by at least one B by using:

```
A.objects.filter(bObjects__isnull=False)
```

if you get duplicates of A objects add `distinct()` after `filter`

Answer (score 1):

If I do not misunderstand, you are looking for [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

```
A.objects.filter(b__isnull=False)
```

- `b__` is the back reference to `class A` since you have a ForeignKey to `class A` in `class B`. you use the class name in lowercase when you are using it in reverse relation.
- `isnull` let you filter records acording to their `NULL` or `NOT NULL` condition.

Comment: The underlying SQL query does have 'WHERE id IS NOT NULL` in this case, which is unnecessary. I would like to use a syntax which results in no such clause. Judging by the numbers here with MySQL, this clause does add a little bit of overhead.

Comment: Then how do you wish to control? In sql, RDBMS have to control whether is there an existing relation between the records. You can also do your filter in python, but that will be worse than filtering unwanted results within the database.

Comment: I just want the SQL query to omit the `WHERE id IS NOT NULL` piece. It is superfluous, as `id`, being a primary key, can never be `NULL`.

Comment: `isnull` controls if there is a reverse relation for the record. `isnull=True` filters `A` objects which have a ForeignKey relation to any `B` object and list `A` objects which have these relations. `isnull=False` means filtered objects have no B object related to them via `ForeignKey`.

Comment: As far as I know, ther is not direct way to do it as you want. You can use [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/) to do it.