# Filtering on Django backreferences

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to query all  objects in a table without backreferences from another model.

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    reference = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

In order to get all `A` objects with no references from any `B` objects, I do

```
A.objects.filter(b__isnull=True)
```

The [Django documentation on `isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) does not mention backreferences at all.

Can I get into trouble with this or is it just poorly documented?

Comment: I can't think of a reason where that wouldn't work, [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21405658/1324033) seems to suggest it is correct

Answer (score 2):

I tried this with Django 1.10.3, using your same code example.

Let's take a look at the raw SQL statement that Django creates:

```
>>> print(A.objects.filter(b__isnull=True).query)
SELECT "backrefs_a"."id" FROM "backrefs_a" LEFT OUTER JOIN "backrefs_b" ON ("backrefs_a"."id" = "backrefs_b"."reference_id") WHERE "backrefs_b"."id" IS NULL
```

Technically, this isn't the exact same SQL that Django will send to the database, but it's close enough. For more discussion, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074224/5044893

If we pretty it up a bit, you can see that the query is actually quite safe:

```
SELECT "backrefs_a"."id"
FROM "backrefs_a"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "backrefs_b" ON ("backrefs_a"."id" = "backrefs_b"."reference_id")
WHERE "backrefs_b"."id" IS NULL
```

The `LEFT` in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ensures that you will get records from A, even when there are no matching records in B. And, because Django won't save a B with a `NULL` **id**, you can rest assured that it will work as you expect.